# How to present view controller from left to right in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uinavigationcontroller

When adding a new controller to the navigation stack:

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(PushedViewController(), animated: true)
```

it appears from the right:

[image]

How can I change the direction of animation to make it appear from the left?

Comment: You want to push or present ViewController?

Comment: Just as a heads-up, this very much goes against Apple's design guidelines and will likely be confusing to your users.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Swift 5.1: Segue from different directions**

Here is a simple extension for different segue directions. (Tested in Swift 5)

It looks like you want to use segueFromLeft() I added some other examples as well.

```
extension CATransition {

//New viewController will appear from bottom of screen.
func segueFromBottom() -> CATransition {
    self.duration = 0.375 //set the duration to whatever you'd like.
    self.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
    self.type = CATransitionType.moveIn
    self.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromTop
    return self
}
//New viewController will appear from top of screen.
func segueFromTop() -> CATransition {
    self.duration = 0.375 //set the duration to whatever you'd like.
    self.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
    self.type = CATransitionType.moveIn
    self.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromBottom
    return self
}
 //New viewController will appear from left side of screen.
func segueFromLeft() -> CATransition {
    self.duration = 0.1 //set the duration to whatever you'd like.
    self.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
    self.type = CATransitionType.moveIn
    self.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromLeft
    return self
}
//New viewController will pop from right side of screen.
func popFromRight() -> CATransition {
    self.duration = 0.1 //set the duration to whatever you'd like.
    self.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
    self.type = CATransitionType.reveal
    self.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromRight
    return self
}
//New viewController will appear from left side of screen.
func popFromLeft() -> CATransition {
    self.duration = 0.1 //set the duration to whatever you'd like.
    self.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
    self.type = CATransitionType.reveal
    self.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromLeft
    return self
   }
}
```

And here is how you implement the above extension:

```
    let nav = self.navigationController //grab an instance of the current navigationController
    DispatchQueue.main.async { //make sure all UI updates are on the main thread.
        nav?.view.layer.add(CATransition().segueFromLeft(), forKey: nil)
        nav?.pushViewController(YourViewController(), animated: false)
    }
```

Comment: This helped. I owned you.

Comment: I have tried to test this in a playground and I get "expression failed to parse, unknown error".

Comment: It's great! Thank you. But I have a question. How can I remove the shadow in this animations? If I use default iOS func pushViewController - new view appears without shadow under it. But if I use your code I see the shadow.

Answer (score 9):

```
let obj = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")as! ViewController
            
let transition:CATransition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.3
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
transition.type = .push
transition.subtype = .fromLeft
self.navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(obj, animated: true)
```

> Whene you use popToViewController that Time

```
 transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
```

Comment: Great answer. Just in order to make it clearer. Add the full code in the popToViewController part. You got my point here dude.

Answer (score 3):

This may help you

```
let nextVc  = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextVc")
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVc!, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here's a **drop-in solution** for you. Add file named `LeftToRightTransitionProxy.swift` with the next content

```
import UIKit

final class LeftToRightTransitionProxy: NSObject {

    func setup(with controller: UINavigationController) {
        controller.delegate = self
    }
}

extension LeftToRightTransitionProxy: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        if operation == .push {
            return AnimationController(direction: .forward)
        } else {
            return AnimationController(direction: .backward)
        }
    }
}

private final class AnimationController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    enum Direction {
        case forward, backward
    }

    let direction: Direction

    init(direction: Direction) {
        self.direction = direction
    }

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.3
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        guard let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to),
            let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from) else {
                return
        }

        let container = transitionContext.containerView
        container.addSubview(toView)

        let initialX: CGFloat
        switch direction {
        case .forward: initialX = -fromView.bounds.width
        case .backward: initialX = fromView.bounds.width
        }
        toView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: initialX, y: 0), size: toView.bounds.size)

        let animation: () -> Void = {
            toView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: toView.bounds.size)
        }
        let completion: (Bool) -> Void = { _ in
            let success = !transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled
            if !success {
                toView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            transitionContext.completeTransition(success)
        }
        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext),
            animations: animation,
            completion: completion
        )
    }
}
```

And here's how you can use it:

```
final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let animationProxy = LeftToRightTransitionProxy()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        animationProxy.setup(with: navigationController!)
    }
}
```

This solution provides animation for **both forward and backward** (`push` and `pop`) directions. 
This can be controlled in `navigationController(_:animationControllerFor:from:to:)` method of your `LeftToRightTransitionProxy` class (just return `nil` to remove animation).

If you need this behaviour for **specific subclass** of `UIViewController` put appropriate checks in `navigationController(_:animationControllerFor:from:to:)` method:

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    if operation == .push && toVC is DetailViewController {
        return AnimationController(direction: .forward)
    } else if operation == .pop && toVC is ViewController {
        return AnimationController(direction: .backward)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used [Hero](https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero) as a solution.

```
import Hero
```

Then in that place where you’re going to show new UIViewController turn the default animation:

```
Hero.shared.defaultAnimation = HeroDefaultAnimationType.cover(direction: .right)
```

Also specify that your UINavigationController is going to use the Hero library:

```
self.navigationController?.hero.isEnabled = true
```

After that you’ll get the expected result even if you’re using the standard pushViewController function:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write your own transition procedure to achieve your needs.

**DOCS from Apple:**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrollercontexttransitioning

**Article:**

https://medium.com/@ludvigeriksson/custom-interactive-uinavigationcontroller-transition-animations-in-swift-4-a4b5e0cefb1e

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn how to do custom transitions (i.e. presenting from right to left) then [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/915-uipresentationcontroller-tutorial-getting-started) is a pretty good tutorial for setting them up.

The key things you need to do are set up a transitioning delegate, a custom presentation controller, and a custom animation controller.

Answer (score -1):

you could use a third party library, you can search them in `github.com`or `cocoacontrols.com` as navigation Drawer

In my case I use this
https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material#NavigationDrawer

others
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=Drawer

https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift

https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu

[image]